# Couldn't load "object". Somehow it went missing?

Tags: python, django, solr, celery

Am using haystack with solr 6.6 for search indexing. Now i want to automatically update indexes when data changes in my models under indexing, so am using celery_haystack for that. Unfortunately, each time index should be updated i get `could not load [app.model.pk]. Somehow it went missing` error

- python 3.6.3
- django 1.11.6
- celery 4.1.0
- django-haystack 2.7.dev0
- celery-haystack 0.10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely after trying and trying i decided to restart the whole system and it just started working, without changing anything